# Retrieving COUNT of a calculated expression

Tags: mysql

I read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) that I can include an argument inside COUNT, to return a calculated value. I'm trying the following but I'm missing something. Can you help? Thanks!

> ```
>   mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME, $connection);
>     $client = "demo/";
>     $result = mysql_query
>     (
>         "SELECT 
>         COUNT(page_max > 126) AS completed 
>         FROM " .SESSIONDB. " 
>         WHERE client = '$client' 
>         AND page = 'interaction.php'
>         "
>     ); 
>     if(mysql_error()) die(DIRECTORY_TITLE . " - Error DBA110 " . mysql_error());
>     // output THE QUERY
>     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
>     {
>         echo $row['completed'];
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please add your table details here.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 "SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS completed 
    FROM " .SESSIONDB. " 
    WHERE client = '$client' AND page_max > 126
    AND page = 'interaction.php'"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN page_max > 126 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed 
FROM table
WHERE client = '$client' 
AND page = 'interaction.php'
```

Or as Nicolò Martini said, move page_max to WHERE condition if you don't need total count of items.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(page_max>126,1,NULL)) AS completed ....
```

`COUNT` counts the number of rows that aren't `NULL`.  This expression turns anything where page_max is greater than 126 into `1` and anything that isn't into `NULL`.

That said, why not just move `page_max` to the `WHERE` condition?

Comment: brilliant thank you - because I want to return a number of specific counts, from inside the same query, page_min, page_max, page_average